# (Excel) conditional formatting based on adjacent cell, whole column

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to highlight the changes in a long list of data, so I would like to have the cell shaded if its value is different than the cell above.  I can implement this for a single pair of cells using conditional formatting, but I can't get it to work for a whole column.  Here's what I want it to look like (I performed this shading manually, for this example):

[image: column]

I tried this, but it doesn't propagate down the column when I select the column.

[image: format]

Comment: That should work, maybe just add an `=` sign? `=A1<>A2`

Comment: Ah, silly me.  That does work!  I was so close.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First time responding to a question on Stack Overflow, so apologies if the formatting on this response is messy.

You will want the formula to read:
{ =A2<>A1 }

[Conditional Formatting Rules Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtU4.png)

Comment: On second glance, it appears as though this formula (and the one referenced by CallumDA) actually highlights the last cell prior to the number changing rather than the first occurrence of the number changing, if that makes sense.

Comment: it depends on your "applies to" range. If that starts at A2 (rather than A1) then you'll get the required effect